# Sites not working after sharepoint 2010 server SP1 & Aug 2012 CU

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, user-profile, logging, cumulative-update

Single server and single farm.

It has SP foundation 2010. I then upgraded it to SP 2010 server SP1 (by first installing SP 2010 server followed by SP 2010 foundation SP1 and then server 2010 SP1 and finally Aug 2012 CU. At the end I rebooted machine and then ran CONFIG utility and then rebooted again).

I see that central admin opens and I am able to create sites etc.

Whats happening is the old site that was there with SP foundation 2010 is not accessible. When I click on it, I get below error,

```
Error
```

An unexpected error has occurred.

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: e6976c4d-0a40-4453-aa6e-2447cbf74ca2

Date and Time: 9/14/2012 10:39:57 AM

I tried to look in the 14 hive logs but I see only "usage" files and log files are zero bytes. The application event log has few errors as listed below.

Event IDs are below

---

### 7043 - Load control template file /_controltemplates/TaxonomyPicker.ascx failed: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.TaxonomyPicker' from assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.

---

2137 - The SharePoint Health Analyzer detected an error.  Drives are running out of free space.
Available drive space is less than twice the value of physical memory. This is dangerous because it does not provide enough room for a full memory dump with continued operation. It also could cause problems with the Virtual Memory swap file:  (CRMLAB01 - C:).

### Examine the failing servers and delete old logs or free space on the drives. For more information about this rule, see "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=142688".

---

5555 - Failure trying to synch web application b7053168-92fe-4764-9b48-6af49cf1444e, ContentDB 290c103d-99e1-467d-814d-5497546b5d0f  Exception message was System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PerfmonInstanceHandle()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ContentDBSynchronizer..ctor(ELogType logType, SPContentDatabase cdb, SPJobState jobState)

### at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.WSSProfileSyncJob.Execute()

---

7362 -Object Cache: The super user account utilized by the cache is not configured. This can increase the number of cache misses, which causes the page requests to consume unneccesary system resources.
 To configure the account use the following command 'stsadm -o setproperty -propertyname portalsuperuseraccount -propertyvalue account -url webappurl'. The account should be any account that has Full Control access to the SharePoint databases but is not an application pool account.
 Additional Data:

### Current default super user account: SHAREPOINT\system

As of now, the newly created web application and it's site atleast renders. I am still testing the old site (that got upgraded from SP foundation to SP server 2010).

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need to rebuild the farm.  From what I am following, you had a Foundation Farm that you tried to install SharePoint Server on top of.  While it will let you run that install, that is not the proper install process and it is known to cause problems.  You should uninstall everything and then install SharePoint Server again.  Ideally you will install using the installs that already include SP1 so that you do not have to do a subsequent update.

After you rebuild the farm you can attach your existing content databases so that your existing site content will still be available.